# Snippet fails to be inserted silently in ST3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have been following [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-preserving-your-wrists-with-sublime-text-snippets-7541662a53f2), [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-insert-a-snippet-from-a-plugin/3651), [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html), [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/snippet-triggering-inside-command/27876/4) and [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View) to create my own template in ST3. So when I create a new file, I preload the file with template content. I have read I should do this with a snippet.

I create a file and try to apply a `snippet` in the new `view`, but nothing happens, I do not get any feedback (not even when I input a wrong snippet name on purpose). My snippet is inside my plugin folder:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\MyPlugin\templ.sublime-snippet
```

My multiple attempts are below:

```
def on_done(...):
        ...
        open(path, 'a').close()
        new_view = self.window.open_file(path)

        # These seem to work, so the view seems valid
        print(new_view.file_name())
        print(new_view.line_height())

        # Attempt 1
        template = """<snippet>
        <content><![CDATA[
        Hello, \${1:this} is a \${2:snippet}.
        ]]></content>
        </snippet>
        """
        new_view.run_command("insert_snippet", {"contents": template})

        # Attempt 2: from the user folder. Nothing happens
        new_view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "name": "Packages/User/templ.sublime-snippet" })

        # Attempt 3: from current (?) folder just in case
        new_view.run_command("insert_snippet", {"name" : "templ.sublime-snippet"})

        # Attempt 4, from the actual plugin folder
        new_view.run_command("insert_snippet", {"name" : "Packages/MyPlugin/templ.sublime-snippet"})

        # Attempt 5, absolute directory
        new_view.run_command("insert_snippet", {"name" : "C:\\Users\\nerea\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3\\Packages\\MyPlugin\\templ.sublime-snippet"})

        # Attempt 6, to check if I mistook the path if I would get any error    
        new_view.run_command("insert_snippet", {"name" : "Packages/User/nonexisting.sublime-snippet"})

         # Attempt 7, nothing either
        new_view.run_command("insert_snippet", {"contents" : "<snippet><content><![CDATA[Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.]]></content></snippet>"})

        # This does nothing either. I supposed that should do something
        new_view.run_command("insert", "wawawiwa")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the view hasn't finished loading the file you specified when you execute the `insert_snippet` command.
I recommend to try this:

```
    new_view = self.window.open_file(path)
    def do_insert():
        if not new_view.is_loading():
            new_view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "name": "Packages/MyPlugin/templ.sublime-snippet" })
        sublime.set_timeout_async(do_insert, 10)
    do_insert()
```

if you are calling `insert_snippet` with the `contents` argument, the API expects just the snippet contents - i.e. `Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.` instead of the surrounding XML.

Note that having a backslash before the dollar in the snippet contents will cause ST to treat the dollar literally instead of delineating tab/edit points.